# How much effort (perhaps in Big O notation?) is required to minimally reduce a truth table?

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I am using some software that generates truth tables based on a BDD. Here is an example:

```
abcde
11110
110x0
10xxx
01110
010x0
00xxx
```

The problem is that this is not very user readable. I would like to see simplified table like this instead:

```
abcde
xxx10
xx0x0
x0xxx
```

How difficult would it be in general for the software to produce a minimized truth table given one an arbitraly sized truth table that is not minimized?

Comment: Looks very much NPish to me. I almost see a connection to a set cover problem.

Comment: Look into [Karnaugh maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map),

Comment: @user58697: "NP" (by which I think you mean "NP-hard") should **not** be equated naively with difficulty.  it is often quite easy to implement algorithms for NP-hard problems that are very useful in practice.

Comment: How many variables and what software are you using ,if I may ask?